# How to filter JIRA by the date a label or fixversion was added/applied

Tags: jira

Given a label or fixVersion in JIRA, it's easy to construct a filter for issues with that label/fixVersion.  Is there a way to filter for issues where the label or fixVersion has been added within a given time period?  (e.g. last 24 hours)

Answer (score 1):

For Fix Version you can use the [`CHANGED` operator](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching+-+Operators+Reference#AdvancedSearching-OperatorsReference-CHANGED) with the `AFTER` predicate to find issues tagged with that version in the last 24 hours:

```
fixVersion CHANGED TO "v1.0" AFTER -24h
```

This won't work for labels:

> This operator can be used with the Assignee, Fix Version, Priority, Reporter, Resolution and Status fields only.